# show dwg,as background not as vector

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, data, vector, dwg

I have some dwg files that i need to show as background on my map, but the DWG is not need to be vector layers, i need only to show them with out the need of using.

if i am trying to convert it to DXF so the QGIS read it wrong, its convert everything to point and losing all the data.

example for dwg file:
[image: DWG pic]

there is any way to show it like it is, without losing all the shaps when trying to convert to vector layer? maybe show it like raster? then what format its should be?

Answer (score 1):

you would need to convert to an image format if you don't want vector.
but that will provide some difficulty in layering with your background. (if you have a raster basemap).
you might need to make the (converted) dwg background transparent to oaverlay with basemap and underlay with other vectors.
It is not clear what the final viewing client is. openlayers, qgis? If going to a wab based map you could create a wms of the layers and that would get you most of the way there.

Comment: I am showing it with OpenLayers, i want to cerate WMS layer but GeoServer cant read the DWG file, and i cant conver t it to shp because then its losing all the data... how else i can create WMS layer with it?

Answer (score 0):

this is a very old post, but here's a nice solution:
https://web-map-service.com/
this solution allows you to upload your DWG file and convert it to a WMS layers to be consumed on any GIS client.
It converts the AutoCAD drawing to tiles, images, so it isn't vector data anymore.
This means that if your DWG is loaded with vectors, the WMS will be loaded faster.
The above solution also allows to to reproject the coordinate system (including scale, rotation and translation) or to choose a specific extent to process.

Let me know if it helped.